# How do I do a pre-order file traversal in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, tree, traversal, preorder

I was looking for a simple bash one-liner for traversing a file system and printing all the files in pre-order arrangement.  It seems as though `find` is not capable of doing this.  I could try to `sort` the results of `find`, but that doesn't seem feasible either.  Is there an easy way to do this in bash?

For example,

```
find .                                                                                                                 
.
./sub2
./sub2/e.txt
./sub1
./sub1/b.txt
./sub1/c.txt
./sub1/sub3
./sub1/sub3/d.txt
./sub1/z.txt
./a.txt
```

It should instead be:

```
.
./a.txt
./sub2
./sub2/e.txt
./sub1
./sub1/b.txt
./sub1/c.txt
./sub1/z.txt
./sub1/sub3
./sub1/sub3/d.txt
```

**What I've tried:**

- looked at all `find` flags.  It cannot print this way.
- looked at all sort flags.  It can not interpret lines as paths and re-order them this way.

This is not pre-order because `./sub1/sub3/d.txt` comes before `./sub1/z.txt`.

Comment: I don't see how `sort` (sorting files by name or timestamp) is related to do preorder traversal of a tree (visiting the entries of a directory before visiting the directory itself). Therefore I find your question unclear. An example would help.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of files and directories, the code you've attempted, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output; in this case a description of the actual order you're looking for (eg, (reverse) alphabetic, last modified date, something else) would also help

Comment: @user1934428 In theory sort could provide an option that recognizes the entries as file paths and organize them via any traversal (pre-order / post-order, etc).  It has nothing to do with lexicographical sorting or timestamps.

Comment: I would expect such a feature rather in `find` than in `sort`. In a directory tree, the files are the leaves of the tree and the (sub-)directories  are the inner nodes. Hence you want to guarantee that the inner nodes are visited later than the leaves.  I found that `find` does it exactly the opposite. Howabout running find, and traversing the list generated by `find` in the  reverse direction (last to first)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this with bash and GNU find:

```
bfind() {
  find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
  find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'bfind "$1"' bash {} \;
}

export -f bfind

bfind .
```

It's slow but does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A bash version:

```bash
findfile_preorder()(
    shopt -s dotglob nullglob
    for p; do
        printf '%s\n' "$p"
        [[ ! -L $p && -d $p ]] && findfile_preorder "$p"/*
    done
)
```

bash globs are sorted, so the output is also:

```
$ mkdir testdir
$ cd testdir
$ mkdir sub{1,2} sub1/sub3
$ touch a.txt sub2/e.txt sub1/{b,c,z}.txt sub1/sub3/d.txt
$ findfile_preorder .
.
./a.txt
./sub1
./sub1/b.txt
./sub1/c.txt
./sub1/sub3
./sub1/sub3/d.txt
./sub1/z.txt
./sub2
./sub2/e.txt
$
```

---

I believe the above algorithm **is** preorder traversal but it seems you also want to output all non-directories before descending the tree:

```bash
findfile_preorder2()(
    shopt -s dotglob nullglob
    local d=()
    for p; do
        if [[ ! -L $p && -d $p ]]; then
            d+=($p)
        else
            printf '%s\n' "$p"
        fi
    done
    for p in "${d[@]}"; do
        printf '%s\n' "$p"
        findfile_preorder "$p"/*
    done
)
```

which gives:

```
$ findfile_preorder2 .
.
./a.txt
./sub1
./sub1/b.txt
./sub1/c.txt
./sub1/z.txt
./sub1/sub3
./sub1/sub3/d.txt
./sub2
./sub2/e.txt
$
```

Comment: In fact, I think my first algorithm is the same as the `find` default (except that `find` operates on unsorted directory contents). cf. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/preorder-traversal-of-n-ary-tree-without-recursion/